# GlassMapper Link not rendered when %20 in subject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, glass-mapper

I have an interesting situation where I am trying to render a link which could be a URL to a site or a mailTo tag.

The issue is that when I put any spaces in the subject field these get converted into %20's when I save the link then the link doesn't get pulled into the rendering at all (it just returns null in the view).

Interestingly if I manually remove the %20's after I save the link (this can be done in the page editor) the link comes through fine!

Now if I save and publish the link returns null but if I manually edit  and remove the %20 GlassMapper grabs the link fine.

Any ideas why GlassMapper wont get the link when there is %20's in there?

Comment: Have you tried using the standard Sitecore HTML Helpers rather than doing this through Glass, to rule out this is not an issue with Sitecore itself?

Comment: It works fine in Sitecore. The issue is definitely with glass mapper

Comment: What version of Sitecore and Glass are you using?

Comment: Sitecore 8.1 initial release.
Glass 4.0.5.54

Comment: Anyone got any thoughts?